# What do I do with this NPC "handout"?

Tags: gm-preparation, shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

I'm setting up to start running some Shadowrun Missions scenarios for my gaming group.  We're starting with Season 2 (available free [here](https://www.shadowruntabletop.com/missions/downloads-season-2/)), converted from SR4 to SR4A.

I'm very confused by the "player handout" document, though.  Some of it makes sense (maps, tracking sheets).  But I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do with the NPC pages.  As one example:

[image: example of NPC page]

This doesn't seem like information that the PCs would have access to, but as the GM, I certainly don't need *three* copies of it for every single important NPC.  It's not even useful to print one and fold in a `_/\` shape because the text would be upside-down.

What is the intent here?  What am I supposed to do with this "handout"?

Answer (score 6):

That is a *Contact Sheet*.

Should the PCs get such NPCs as their contacts, you can hand them a copy of that contact sheet so they will know what kind of information is available from that NPC. So, whenever you needed a contact, you could quickly look at those "cards" and see if any of them could be of any use.

Note that his physical stats are missing, which is to point out that they are useless in combat situations and should not be forced into one, though that is entirely at GM discretion.

Comment: Ah, so the idea is that they’d get cut up and given one strip to each player to keep for reference?  That makes sense.  Thanks for solving this mystery!

Answer (score -3):

I will take a crack at this, but fair warning I have played 5E in 1 long and 1 single day campaign and a 1st time DM in another.

1. If you have a player that is willing to play that NPC for a bit then share it.
2. IF you are just running the NPC yourself then share whatever of the desc that you want. If your players start asking questions about that NPC then use the card to provide answers. But how much is up to you.
3. I am assuming that anything other than the background info and name is secret and not shared but for your use only (e.g. skills, gear, contact, etc).
4. Have no idea why 3 but maybe that is a fluke, and there in case you run it a 2nd or 3rd time and need clean copies.

I hope this helps but it is rather generic NPC type advice and I expect that you might have already answered it yourself.

Good luck and I hope your game went well and all involved had fun. 
Joe

Comment: HI, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for information on how this site works. Thanks for taking the time to answer, some of your points are good. However we are looking for answer that can be supported with rules and/or experience and unfortunately it seems you have no experience running Shadowrun (the game this question is about) and that is likely why you are attracting downvotes. Don't be discouraged we do have lots of [tag:dnd-5e] question that you can answer, remember to support your answer and not just give opinions. Good luck and happy gaming!